# Split up key:value data into columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file with key:value data in one of the colums:

```
id|name|age|data
1|steve|5 |a:5,b:1,e:7
2|john |10|c:3,b:2,e:4
3|jack |12|e:4,c:2,d:7,b:9
```

I'd like to split it all up as follows:

```
id|name |age|a|b|c|d|e
1 |steve|5  |5|1| | |7
2 |john |10 | |2|3| |4
3 |jack |12 | |9|2|7|4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started.

```
Sub split_and_sort()
    Dim rw As Long, v As Long, vKEYs As Variant, vPAIR As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet5")   '<~~ set this wroksheet reference properly!
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(1, 5) = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count + 4)
                For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
                    vKEYs = Split(.Cells(rw, 4).Value2, Chr(44))
                    .Cells(rw, 4).Clear
                    For v = LBound(vKEYs) To UBound(vKEYs)
                        vPAIR = Split(vKEYs(v), Chr(58))
                        If CBool(UBound(vPAIR)) Then
                            If IsError(Application.Match(vPAIR(0), .Rows(1), 0)) Then _
                                .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = vPAIR(0)
                            .Cells(rw, Application.Match(vPAIR(0), .Rows(1), 0)) = vPAIR(1)
                        End If
                    Next v
                Next rw
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you have cells in column D without values or rogue values that will not split first on a comma and then again on a colon, you might have to add some error control

[image: Split and Sort]